# PHP and the euro symbo

Tags: php, unicode

Lets assume the following string is entered into a form and submitted to a PHP script.

"€ should encode as &euro;"

I would like to know how to actually get € to encode as &euro;  htmlentities() doesn't do it, what voodoo is needed in order to get that to encode properly (and others like it)?

Comment: The statement "€ to encode as €" is nonsense... how do you want € to be encoded? What are you doing with this string once PHP has it?

Comment: Ah, I see your edit now. :-) That makes more sense.

Comment: Any reason why you want it encoded as an entity? (You could just transmit the € directly to the user.)

Comment: I can't convince mysql to accept the original character despite the collation being utf8.

Comment: actually I just checked and I can insert € directly into the DB, which means PHP is doing something to the string on insert.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Ensure pages are served as `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8` (via `header()` and/or `<meta>`). 2. Call `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` to set the PHP<->MySQL connection to match. 3. Ensure MySQL table columns are using a UTF-8 `COLLATION`. Indeed, you should be storing and outputting `€` directly and not attempting to HTML-encode it. Don't use `htmlentities()`, use `htmlspecialchars()`, which only encodes the basic characters that really need it, leaving Unicode alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities). But you need to make sure to use the proper character set as `htmlentities`’ default character set [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) does not contain that character; but [ISO 8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) for example does:

```
var_dump(htmlentities("\xA4", ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-15') === '&euro;');  // bool(true)
```

Here the `"\xA4"` will result in the byte 0xA4 that is the code of `€` in ISO 8859-15.

So just make sure to use a character set that contains that character.

Comment: I've seen this advice in various places around the web, but it isn't working.  I've tried htmlentities($descr_text, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-7',false), and htmlentities($descr_text, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-15',false); and they are not working.  This is very aggravating, do you have an explanation for why this would not be working?

Comment: @Fred: The *charset* value needs to reflect the actual character set. So what is `$descr_text` encoded with?

Comment: I have no clue, and I don't know how to find out.  The following: mb_detect_encoding($descr_text,'auto'); returns false.  How do I go about finding out?

Comment: @Fred: Well, where does the value of `$descr_text` come from? If you typed that value with an editor, check its character encoding in its settings.

Comment: It's coming from an input form from firefox.  Also, if you know of any articles for handling unicode in PHP I'd appreciate a link.  Obviously I'm extremely ignorant when it comes to handling unicode in PHP.

Comment: @Fred: In that case specify the accepted character set with the [`accept-charset` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset).

Comment: bam, that's what I was missing.  Thank you Gumbo.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "€ should encode as " . htmlentities("€", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```